# How to multicast single UDP to a group of my instances in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a machine which is streaming video to one of my AWS Linux server with UDP, then users access my Linux server to obtain the video stream with WebRTC. It is working fine. But If my want to scale it up, I need something to take my UDP stream and multicast it to all of my servers.

I know AWS has a transit gateway multicast which does exactly what I wanted, but it is only available in US-east:
[Working with multicast - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/working-with-multicast.html)

May I know how can I multicast my single UDP stream to my VM scale set?

---

Maybe let me explain a bit more in pictures:
I want to broadcast the UDP stream to multiple server instances, from this:

[image]

To This:
[image]
I've looked into [n2n](https://github.com/ntop/n2n), seems like it is possible to broadcast UDP to its network, not sure if we have any better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** [IP Multicast on AWS Transit Gateway is Now Available in Europe (Frankfurt), South America (São Paulo), Middle East (Bahrain), Asia Pacific (Hong Kong) and Asia Pacific (Seoul) AWS Regions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/ip-multicast-on-aws-transit-gateway-is-now-available-in-europe-frankfurt-south-america-sao-paulo-middle-east-bahrain-asia-pacific-hong-kong-and-asia-pacific-seoul-aws-regions/)

Multicast is not available in Amazon VPCs. The new **transit gateway multicast domain** is a way of providing multicast functionality but at the moment (August 2020) it is only available in selected regions.

Thus, you cannot use multicast in any other region.

One way to workaround this issue is to put a "multicast listener" on the sending instance that then re-sends the traffic to a list of "destination instances". This is *sending* the traffic rather than *multicasting* the traffic. You might find some sample code on the Internet for this type of re-sending instance, but it isn't a very 'clean' way to do things.

If you use **NDI instead of WebRTC**, then the NewTek NDI Tools have an Access Manager that allows you to point to a central Discovery Server on one instance, which overcomes the need to use multicast.

Comment: Oh my god! They just announced more supported regions yesterday, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you @JohnRotenstein!